# leetcode - number of islands, RecursionError

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to solve the famous problem of "number of islands" from leetcode. (link : https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/)

I solved this solution using BFS, but I got this error :
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

Why I get this error?
I cant figure why.

Here is my code:

```
def numIslands(grid):    
    islands = 0
    for i in range(0, len(grid)):
        for j in range(0, len(grid[0])):
            if(grid[i][j] == "1"):
                islands += 1
                marksZero(grid, i, j)

    print(islands)           
    return islands
                    
                    
def marksZero(grid, i, j):

    if(grid[i][j] == "0"):
        return
    
    grid[i][j] = 0
    if(i - 1 >= 0):
        marksZero(grid, i - 1, j)
    if(i + 1 < len(grid)):
        marksZero(grid, i + 1, j)
    if(j - 1 >= 0):
        marksZero(grid, i, j - 1)
    if(j + 1 < len(grid[0])):
        marksZero(grid, i, j + 1)

numIslands([["1","1","1","1","0"],["1","1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0","0"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning int instead of string to your grid,therefore condition creates infinite loop.
Change `grid[i][j] = "0"`

```
def numIslands(grid):
    islands = 0
    for i in range(0, len(grid)):
        for j in range(0, len(grid[0])):
            if(grid[i][j] == "1"):
                islands += 1
                marksZero(grid, i, j)

    print(islands)
    return islands


def marksZero(grid, i, j):

    if(grid[i][j] == "0"):
        return

    grid[i][j] = "0"
    if(i - 1 >= 0):
        marksZero(grid, i - 1, j)
    if(i + 1 < len(grid)):
        marksZero(grid, i + 1, j)
    if(j - 1 >= 0):
        marksZero(grid, i, j - 1)
    if(j + 1 < len(grid[0])):
        marksZero(grid, i, j + 1)


numIslands([["1", "1", "1", "1", "0"],
            ["1", "1", "0", "1", "0"],
            ["1", "1", "0", "0", "0"],
            ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some visit matrix to make sure you are in each cell only once

something like that

```
visit = [[False ]* 5 ]* 4

def marksZero(grid, i, j):
    if visit[i][j]:
        return
    visit[i][j]=True
```